# Storing/handling exceptions in ViewModel

Tags: java, android, mvvm, exception, viewmodel

This is coming from someone with relatively little experience.
I am trying to develop an application for android using the MVVM approach.

Lets say I have `models` that describe data and fetch it, `viewmodels` that act as converters that change model information into view information and pass commands from views to models. Would it be appropriate to store exceptions that happen inside models in `viewmodels` so that views would be able to display them? If so, what would be the best way to do that without having to use excessive amounts of `if (error != null)` checks.

For example:

```
class userVM {

    UserService service;
    List<User> users;
    Integer selectedUserIndex;
    Throwable error;

    ...

    void fetchAll(){
        try {
            this.users = service.getAll();
            this.selectedUserIndex = null;
            this.error = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.users = null;
            this.selectedUserIndex = null;
            this.error = e;
        }
    }

    // ... getters for the members ...
}
```

Comment: ["throw early, catch late"](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/12/04/exceptions.html) If you do catch them, you'll end up having to handle them in ugly ways.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I read the article. 
In a sense this is as late as it gets to catch them, the next step would be to display data (or error) on a screen...